# Bit set in C its not give me right output?

Tags: c, struct

Its my struct block i want to hold one bit.

```
struct bitset {
    int number: 1;
};
typedef struct bitset bit;
```

But code always give me 46 or 47 output. I didnt understand it.

```
int main() {
    bit x;
    x.number = 1;
    printf("%d", x);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why aren't you using `printf("%d",x.number);`?

Comment: Pretty sure you are attempting to exploit undefined behavior.  You effectively casting a struct with a bit field to an int.

Comment: For a signed integer with 1 bit, `1` might not be a valid value

Comment: Firstly thank you for suggrstion Fiddling Bits.I tried but output -1.

Comment: It's not like a decent compiler won't warn you. So read the warning and deal with it. The typedef does not help you here. Once more it's only obfuscating the fact that you're dealing with a struct.

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to accomplish, why you are doing it this way, and why you expect the result you do?

Comment: As @Ajay says, a 1-bit signed integer can have two possible values: `-1` and `0`. Perhaps you want `unsigned`.

Comment: I want to use in output 0 , when i will give a x.number 0 or 1

Comment: @Wearher Vane but bits like 2^0 or 2^1 yeah like that. It has to be 1 ?

Comment: On Linux, the result is 1, not 47 or 48. And gcc only complains about a missing `;` between the struct and typedef.

Comment: What compiler are you using and what was the command line used to invoke it?

Comment: im using devC++ 5.11 compiler

Comment: @LjmDullaart---thank you i fixxed

Comment: Footnote 125 of the C11 standard draft is relevant here: "*As specified in 6.7.2 above, if the actual type specifier used is **int** or a typedef-name defined as **int**, then it is implementation-defined whether the bit-field is signed or unsigned.*"

Comment: @ChristianGibbons---really thank you my friend now i understand why. Might i ask you question? which compiler would you recommend me ? im using windows

Comment: [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/) is a good and well maintained open source compiler.

Comment: Thank for all feedback guys. Now how can i finish or close this question. im newbie in stackflow

Comment: Since there are no answers, you don't need to do anything.  Good luck!

Comment: I am afraid I cannot make any recommendations as I do not develop on Windows.

Answer (score 2):

The code causes undefined behaviour by using an incorrect format specifier. The `%d` format specifier must correspond to an argument of type `int`, but you pass a struct by value instead.

Being undefined behaviour, the standard places no requirements on the behaviour of the program , so you should not expect any particular output or behaviour.

Also, it is possible that the bitfield is signed and as such could only store `0` or `-1` anyway. Use `unsigned int number: 1` to guarantee being able to store `1`.

Comment: experience talks! +1

Comment: I actually wanted to get around to explaining the finer points in my answer, but my 7 month old grand-child has been rather demanding this afternoon.

Answer (score 1):

From [C-99](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) 6.7.2.1 Structure and union specifiers #10 (emphasis is mine):

> An implementation may allocate any addressable storage unit large
>   enough to hold a bitfield. If enough space remains, a bit-field that
>   immediately follows another bit-field in a structure shall be packed
>   into adjacent bits of the same unit. If insufficient space remains,
>   whether a bit-field that does not fit is put into the next unit or
>   overlaps adjacent units is implementation-defined. **The order of
>   allocation of bit-fields within a unit (high-order to low-order or
>   low-order to high-order) is implementation-defined. The alignment of
>   the addressable storage unit is unspecified.**

Emphasis mine.  The only reasonable way to access the field is with `x.number`.  Pass that as the argument to your `printf` call and it should work fine (although, see my final addendum below).

---

So, what all that says is, the alignment of the struct may not be the same as that of the bit field.  The entire structure is not even required to be sizeof(int), but you can access any bit field as the type the field is declared as.

---

As @M.M points out, a signed, single-bit field will be interpreted as a negative value.  According to [C-99](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) 6.7.2.1 Structure and union specifiers #8:

> ...In addition, a member may be declared to consist of a specified
>   number of bits (including a sign bit, if any)...

So while you can store a 1 in `x.number` (signed or unsigned), when you read it back out as an integer, it will be interpreted as -1 due to [sign extension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_extension).  For single bit fields, it is almost always best to use unsigned bit fields, if your compiler will allow it (most support it today).  You can always use a bit mask to check the relevant bit (assuming [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement)), but that just gets ugly and kind of defeats the purpose of using single-bit fields.

Whether you use signed or unsigned for multi-bit fields, depends on what you are using them for.  If you're using them for numbers, then numeric range decides whether you want signed or unsigned.  If you are treating them as an array of bit flags, it really doesn't matter because you'll be applying bit masks to interpret them anyway, but it's still easier for diagnostic readouts, if they are unsigned (lower cognitive load when the unused most significant bits are all zero).

Comment: Apologies for dribbling this out. My 7 mo. old grand-daughter is teething.